# Displaying Raw Data From Image File Using TextBox or RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, textbox, richtextbox, binary-data

My program reads a DDS image file and stores it as a byte array. I want to be able to show the users the raw data in a TextBox form so at first I convert the byte array to a string using the following code:

```
string data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

I then set the TextBox text:

```
textBox.Text = data;
```

The problem I am having is the text box is not showing all the data. Here is a screenshot of how it looks:

[image: TextBox view]

As you can see only the first few characters are displayed. I am assuming this is because the string contains a null terminator which the TextBox interprets as the end of the string. Here is a copy paste of the first 50 or so characters in the string which I copied directly from the debugger watch window:

DDS |\0\0\0\a\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\

As you can see the first null character comes right after "DDS |" which explains why that's all that shows up in the TextBox.

What I want to be displayed is similar to what you see if you edit the raw DDS file with a text editor such as Notepadd++.

Opening the DDS file in Notepad++ produces the following:

[image: Notepad++ view]

My question is, how do I get my TextBox (or RichTextBox) to show the data in the same way that Notepad++ shows it?

Comment: Have you tried using the String.Replace function to swap out the null characters for something else?

Comment: No I have not but that's a good idea. I assume Notepad++ is doing something similar. Or even fancier, drawing special symbols for things that cannot be displayed (the symbol for null, for example).

Comment: According to the accepted answer [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1641116.aspx/1) you should be able to do something like this: `Replace("\0", @"\0")`.

Comment: I have never seen the @ symbol used like that before. What does it mean to put @ in front of a string such as you have shown?

Comment: Using the @ in front of the string causes the escape sequence to be ignored. It will display as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use this:

```
textbox.Text = data.Replace("\0", @"\0");
```

This will force the textbox to actually show a backslash followed by a zero where the nulls would be. Alternatively, you could replace the nulls with some other character or string.

Comment: That is precisely what I did as per you suggestion.

Comment: I should add that if you allow editing and saving you will have to revert the "\0"s back to nulls like this: `textbox.Text.Replace(@"\0", "\0")`

Comment: I figured so. I thought I'd just add that tidbit in case anyone tried to use it for an editable file.