# Reading Binary File With ASCII(NUL,ESC etc) and Characters to a richtextbox(Raw Data Representation similar to Notepad++)

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me in providing the source code for the below post.

[Displaying Raw Data From Image File Using TextBox or RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352442/displaying-raw-data-from-image-file-using-textbox-or-richtextbox)

I just want the Notepad++ Content in the above post to be displayed in a richtextbox.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
string data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
richTextBox.Text = data;
```

Comment: Its not working NUL is replaced with a string value of \0. I want NUL(ASCII Value) to be displayed.

Comment: Edited so it will no longer replace null